# Pass the events(key or touch) from Service to active application

Tags: android, service

I like to create service which will send the events to current active application like key up, key down, touch motion event, etc...
For example

1. Service will run with some timer.
2. Open browser and view some page
3. After some time, browser should move top to bottom automatically (ie events are passed from service to browser).

Q1. Is it possible? yes, how if no, why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

Fortunately, no.

> if no, why

Security. Allowing Application A to force input events into Application B, -- outside of carefully controlled situations like GUI testing -- would open too many doors for malware to exploit.